# Problem with escaped characters in attributes

Tags: theming

The default [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) is implemented as

```
function theme_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

[`drupal_attributes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_attributes/7) is implemented as

```
function drupal_attributes(array $attributes = array()) {
  foreach ($attributes as $attribute => &$data) {
    $data = implode(' ', (array) $data);
    $data = $attribute . '="' . check_plain($data) . '"';
  }
  return $attributes ? ' ' . implode(' ', $attributes) : '';
}
```

and [`check_plain()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) as

```
function check_plain($text) {
  return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Since [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is being called with `ENT_QUOTES`, single quotes in my title and alt text on the image are being escaped as `&#039;` and double quotes as `&#quot;`, so hovers look weird.

Is there an acceptable, safe, secure way to handle this situation?

Comment: tiptoeing gently here, but are you sure you aren't double check_plain()ing them somewhere along the line?  because here at least I see alt and title attrs with both in them that show up fine.

Comment: @Jimajamma I don't think that's what's happening, this code: `print theme('image', array('path' => 'test', 'alt' => "'test'"));` produces this: `<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://sitename.com/test" alt="&#039;test&#039;" />`

Comment: right @clive and here that produces a nice pale yellow hover box with 'test' in it, unless I am really confused.

Comment: @Jimajamma My bad I see what you mean. What browser are you using?

Comment: I see nicely formatted alts and titles on safari and chrome on a mac and chrome and ie on a pc.  I do know in the not too distant past I had a couple `'alt' => check_plain($foo)`'s out there that I had to clean up though :)

Comment: @Jimajamma  Write that up as an answer for future reference  :/  I thought I tested this through the whole chain.  check_plain() wasn't the direct culprit; using a field's safe_value (which will call check_plain() when the field is attached) instead of value was the root problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you aren't `check_plain()`ing the value before calling it, eg, don't do:

```
... theme('image', array('path' => 'test.jpg', 'alt' => check_plain($foo));
```

or otherwise use a $value that has been processed by any 'safe' filters.